# Unity 3d black skinned Objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I have purchased an asset from Unity 3d Asset store and my unity 3d project is on Android platform , but when I import my asset all its textures is black

I have bought - https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/28304

and it all works fine on PC platform or windows mobile platform , I am 
experiencing this on Android Platform

This is what I am experiencing.....
[image]

Comment: What format are the textures in?

Comment: Have you tried switching to mobile-friendly shaders?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue , you will have to change/swap the shader on mobile or edit the shader code .... Not all shaders work on mobile devices

Comment: try explaining how to do it